# Improve the response of this circuit

Tags: transistors, pwm, opto-isolator, level-shifting, negative-voltage

I designed this circuit (shown below) to level shift an input PWM (10 kHz 5% duty) signal (from microcontroller, 0/+3V3) to 0 and -12V. When the input PWM is HIGH (+3V3) the output is at 0V while when the PWM is LOW (0V) the output is at -12V.

[image: CCT]

The circuit operation (actual response graph) can be seen below;

[image: actual response]

I wish to improve the circuit response hence matching the desired response graph (shown below). I also wish to stay limited to the basic components i.e., resistors, capacitors, transistors (2N3904/2N3906) and opto-couplers (4N25/4N26/4N33). I also need to keep isolation and a small duty cycle PWM input (<= 5%).

[image: desired response]

Any tips/design changes are greatly apricated, Thanks.

Comment: These are pretty short pulses for an optocoupler

Comment: @po.pe, I agree. I increased the duty cycle to 10% and the circuit behaved somewhat better. To be more realistic, isolation is not critical for this design (I did it to safeguard my micro from mistakes since working with -12V, etc), do you think that if I remove the 4N25 and replace with a 2N3904 I would get a better response like in the "desired response" graph while keeping with the <= 5% PWM? Thanks.

Comment: The suggestions below about replacing the opto make sense.  But have you probed the output of the opto to see if that's what's limiting your speed?

Comment: @SteveSh, Not yet, I am still simulating, hence trying to find the optimal solution without buying any parts. Do you think that the 4N25 is the main limiting factor for this?

Comment: Ahhh, OK.  I thought the picture were actual 'scope captures.  In this case, put a simulation probe on pin 5 of the opto.

Comment: @SteveSh, in this image ([link](https://ibb.co/Zc54v7D)) you can see the waveform at pin 5 of the 4N25, I think this is the problem, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace the 4N25 with a logic-output optoisolator such as the [TLP2363](http://file:///C:/Users/Spehro/Downloads/TLP2363_datasheet_en_20210112.pdf) (there are various others, some of them with second sources) you will improve the performance. Internally, they use an IC chip with a photodiode, rather than a phototransistor.

Compare the switching time of the 4N25 with your load of a few hundred ohms (from [this](https://www.vishay.com/docs/81864/4n25x000.pdf) datasheet):

[image]

Your pulse width at 5%/10kHz is 5us, so the switching time is nowhere near fast enough to get an output pulse that resembles the input pulse.

---

Edit: If you don't need isolation, the opto-isolator is not doing much useful.

Also, the 33 ohm resistor dissipates more than 4W when on, which could be an issue if the resistor is not capable of that much pulsed (or in a fault state, continuous) power.

Here is a similar circuit with MOSFETs. You can add a CMOS inverter in front of the circuit if you want to retain the same logic as you have now.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So, did I understand you correctly, I will get an output pulse if I increase the PWM switching frequency? I apricate the fact that you provided the above solutions but as mentioned above I wish to use components that I have available.

Comment: Decrease the PWM frequency and thus lengthen the pulse (while still keeping 5% duty cycle) will help with your current circuit. Getting rid of the 4N25 will help a lot.

Comment: Agreed, I reduced the PWM frequency to 5 kHz and obtained better results (much better), Thanks! Unfortunately, the PWM frequency has to be >= 10 kHz since with this I am sampling a fixed 1 kHz sinusoidal signal, hence lowering the PWM frequency is not an option, while, yes removing the 4N25 is an option. By any chance, do you know how I can isolate the microcontroller pin without optocouplers, if possible?

Comment: There are many ways of doing isolation, but if you just want protection take a series resistor of value X (say 1K) from the MCU pin to your circuit with non-5V rail(s), split it in 2 (say 510+510) and connect the junction to ground through a 5V unipolar TVS or zener diode.

Comment: All right, thanks for the idea. Much apricated!

Answer (score 1):

IF you simulate with the 4N25 you can achieve what you want.

When you saturate Vce the hFE drops towards 10% of a very low CTR already.

This emitter follower offers the high current gain you required.  In some ways, it is [overkill](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDCCsCmC0CcIDsA6MBGMkAs6BMAzNgGzEAcSZxI2BImNeUc66AUAC715kh7YR0xCPwiCQsISiRFi-JEjxKyeeNnAo8xSAUUE8kMq0oE19MBAAm0AGYBDAK4AbDmwDu9YfXhMhI-uBsAE4S2LzoPuDeTCJIYO4g8NQRvjzRgR744ZF%206fEASonJkUn02OpiNBCQUWIokGyFuTzhXgQE1JUCEvi1Gg0hzZDJXi1RmBZsAOZRShV8w7VsAPKeIot4YLwGnYECSOORYenshbDHKRKll%20h85haCKMQH6E8HdVicRXwBWT-zt0kr3gILIRngkCQmEoIIkYE02gMULIODApjkNQmIGs9mcrhCoj4W2422J-mC3zmlLB4we8RmhM2226VLECVKY2aNPiAjolzG%20ggBEgMUSAH0smKwGLsDolBLgSCQXF4GQwAItkgpWgLOgpRK2EA).

[image]

The 22R is optional and only affects the 0V output level by ~ 100mV.
The -12V level is exact as the driver cuts off with low current levels.

Comment: How closely do you think that simulation might reflect reality?

Comment: Hi @Tony Stewart EE75, first of all thanks for your solution. So, I built your proposed circuit (see this [link](https://ibb.co/ZxjG590)), Unfortunately it didn’t work as yours (see this [link](https://ibb.co/SsdrdYF)). I am using Proteus 8.10 SP3 to simulate, any idea what’s causing this? Shall I try the circuit in hardware?

Comment: I guess not at all @Spehro Pefhany

Comment: Try this https://tinyurl.com/yeakanyu

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 it worked kind off, please see the following links (https://ibb.co/fDhGN7w and https://ibb.co/Dttd4D2). I had to change the 1 kOhms resistor to 4.7 kOhms. Can you kindly explain what the res/cap network is doing at the input of the 4N25? Thanks!

Comment: The cap is optional as it just boosts the edges.  Where are your specs for latency, rise/fall time?  It kind of works much better but faster Optos will improve this.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75, see this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJTh5.jpg, this is my desired response. Thanks

Comment: If you cannot define in us or ns, then you are unable to meet spec without one. Not possible with anything you  have tried. Follow best practices for half bridge drivers with a controlled dead-band.